# Using map in liquid templates

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I recently upgraded Jekyll, and `map` doesn't seem to work in my liquid templates anymore. Before I had

```
{{ page.categories | map: "capitalize" | join ", " }}
```

which worked as expected, producing

```
Programming, Ember, d3
```

but now it produces

```
 , ,
```

There is a `array_to_sentence_string` function included in Jekyll, but this doesn't capitalize the categories.

Has anybody else run into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please update to Jekyll's latest version in case you didn't already. The guys working on it are constantly fixing bugs and improving it.

Well, I got it working here. I created a new Jekyll site using `jekyll new test` and modified my index.html:

```
---
layout: default
title: Your New Jekyll Site
categories: [my, new, site]
---

<p>{{ page.categories | map: "capitalize" | join: ", " }}</p>
```

When I build it, `My, New, Site` is appearing correctly. So, try to use correct YAML array syntax (`[..., ..., ...]`), upgrade to latest version of Jekyll and it should work. :)

Comment: Awesome, awesome, awesome. Thank you. Not sure where I got this from (my brain?) but my syntax was (item item item).